# Command abbreviation

Tags: key-bindings, commands, help

After running `M-x magit-status` Emacs provided me this suggestion in the mini-buffer:

```
You can run the command ‘magit-status’ with M-x m-stat RET
```

Is this a built-in feature of emacs? If not, does anyone know which package provide it? Or is this all limited to magit?

Comment: You can check by running Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`), add `magit`, and look to see if the command is there.  If not, it's something in your init file, which you can bisect recursively until you find the lines that add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a general "feature", which was added in Emacs 25.1.  `C-h n` (`view-emacs-news`) tells you this:

> - Editing Changes in Emacs 25.1
>
>   - `M-x` suggests shorthands and ignores obsolete commands for completion.

This suggesting is done in function `execute-extended-command` (specifically, in its helper function `execute-extended-command--shorter`).  It is controlled by user option **`suggest-key-bindings`**.