# Display time of "You can run the command ... with ..." minibuffer hints

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

I type in, for example, `M-x occur` and it says `You can run the command occur with M-s o`.

How can I make that last hint display for more than one second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command abbreviation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34710/command-abbreviation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It defaults to 2 seconds, so you shouldn't need to do anything for it stay for more than one second ;-)

But if 2 isn't enough, just customize `suggest-key-bindings`.

Comment: ;; extend it to 10 seconds. Add this to a startup file if you want it as a default. (setq suggest-key-bindings 10)